# Error arising from Firebase Deploy command

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

So after some hiccups I managed to initiate the firebase cloud functions. I chose python as my language, but when I goto deploy this function. I get the following error:

> Error: Failed to find location of Firebase Functions SDK: Missing
> virtual environment at venv directory. Did you forget to run
> 'python3.11 -m venv venv'?

I tried searching but could not find a proper solution to it. Would really appreciate some help with this please. Thanks

```
 CloudFunction %  firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'anychecklist'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: Failed to find location of Firebase Functions SDK: Missing virtual environment at venv directory. Did you forget to run 'python3.11 -m venv venv'?
```

Comment: Is your question about creating a virtual environment? Have read any tutorials on getting started with Python? Try this tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/ Edit your post with more details.

Comment: No, so I just want to upload this function I've written to firebase.

Comment: Have you checked this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5873)?